# Can I contact this man's probation officer?

Tags: criminal-law, new-york-state, criminal-record, safety

My parents and I live in Suffolk County, New York.

In January 2017 my father's friend began living with us.  During this time, my father's friend was arrested and convicted of animal neglect and abuse.

I believe this man is currently on probation. I have not looked up his probation officer.

My mother and I have expressed both to my father and to this man that we do not want him to live with us.

My father does not put pressure on this man to leave and the man refuses to leave.

There have been numerous verbal fights and altercations between this man, my mother, and me.  I believe my mother's name is on the title of the house that he refuses to leave and her name is on the title of the car that he uses without her consent.

I want to know if I  can contact this man's probation officer. Are there grounds for me to do this? I understand this man is not committing crimes per se but he is not living in good conditions, he is living at our home against half the home's will, and he is not taking steps to improve his life or stay out of trouble in the future. Would a probation officer in Suffolk County, New York investigate his living situation? I understand a probation officer is not a social worker.

Do I have valid grounds to contact the probation officer?

Comment: As edited, this question does not ask for specific legal advice. i havb also removed a good deal of inforamtion not relevant to the question, or at best marginally relevant, but which might support a request for legal advice. As edited I do not think this should be closed as a request for legal advice, because it no longer asks "what should i do?"

Answer (score 2):

May you contact his probation officer? Yes, the First Amendment protects your right to contact the government to complain about your grievances, even if the government cannot or will not resolve them.

Should you contact his probation officer? You should ask a lawyer. It sounds like you and your mother may have assaulted the guy, so inviting law enforcement into this relationship could be stickier than you're thinking.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand this man is not committing crimes per se but he is not living in good conditions, he is living at our home against half the home's will, and he is not taking steps to improve his life or stay out of trouble in the future.

If that man is driving your mother's car without her consent, he is committing a crime. The next time he drives your mother's car without her consent, she can call the police and report him for joyriding.